# Ajax hide deleted element(object)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Learning Django and can't find solution. How hide deleted object on page.

html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<main class="container my-4">
    <h3 class="my-4 border-bottom pb-1">Адреса <a href="{% url 'add_address' %}" class="float-right btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus">  Add address</i></a></h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {% include 'user/user-sidebar.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                {% for add in addbook %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3 {% if add.status %}border-secondary shadow{% endif %} address{{add.id}} address">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="box-element">{{add.address}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">{{add.mobile}}</p>
                        </div>
                        {% if add.status %}
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success check{{add.id}} check"></i>
                            <button data-address="{{add.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info activate-address btn{{add.id}} actbtn" style="display:none;" >Activate</button>
                            <button data-address="{{add.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-address"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                            <a href="{% url 'update-address' add.id %}" class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        {% else %}
                        <div class="card-footer footer{{add.id}}">
                            <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-check-circle text-success check{{add.id}} check"></i>
                            <button data-address="{{add.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info activate-address btn{{add.id}} actbtn">Activate</button>
                            <button data-address="{{add.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-address"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                            <a href="{% url 'update-address' add.id %}" class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

js

```js
$(document).on('click','.delete-address',function(){
    var _aId=$(this).attr('data-address');
    var _vm=$(this);
    // Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url:'/delete-address',
        data:{
            'id':_aId,
        },
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend:function (){
            _vm.attr('disabled', true)
        },
        success:function(){
            $("_aId").hide();
        }
    });
    // End
})
```

What I must put in `success:function(){}` to make the remote address disappear after the button is clicked, without page refresh?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove? Is it the `card`?

Comment: No, not card. It's users addressbook and function deleting one address. The function is working. The address is removed from the database, but the user sees it until they refresh the page.

Comment: Check my answer below. It should get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the `.card`, [`.parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to target the `.col-md-4` and finally [`.remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove it from the DOM.

Change the javascript part to something like this

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-address',function(){
    var _aId=$(this).attr('data-address');
    var _vm=$(this).attr('disabled', true);
    // Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url:'/delete-address',
        data:{
            'id':_aId,
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(){
            _vm.closest('.card').parent().remove();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it works. Now I will try to understand how it works. I thought it would be necessary to add something to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

.remove() will work. You have to select the right dom element.

```js
  success:function(){
                $("_aId").remove();
            }
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out right element to hide (remove). I've tried various combinations to determine the element to be removed, but so far without success.

Answer (score 0):

you need modify it

```js
beforeSend:function (){
   //_vm.attr('disabled', true)
   $(_vm).attr('disabled', true)
},
```

Because "_vm" does not correspond to a jquery object

Comment: I tried this solution but nothing changed. The address is removed, but continues to be displayed on the page until it is reloaded.